# Сортировка массива по значению параметра

Tags: php, opencart

```
foreach ($setting['butopbanner_module'] as $key=>$value)
            {

                $slider_image = html_entity_decode($value['slider_image'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $link = html_entity_decode($value['link'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $title = html_entity_decode($value['title'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $description = html_entity_decode($value['description'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $color_title = html_entity_decode($value['color_title'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $color_description = html_entity_decode($value['color_description'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $bg_color = html_entity_decode($value['bg_color'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
                $sort = html_entity_decode($value['sort'][$this->config->get('config_language_id')], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

                $data['butopbanner'][]=array(
                    'image'=>$slider_image,
                    'title'=>$title,
                    'description'=>$description,
                    'color_title'=>$color_title,
                    'color_description'=>$color_description,
                    'bg_color'=>$bg_color,
                    'sort'=>$sort
                );
            }
```

Как можно сортировать массив по параметру **sort**

платформа Opencart, тут код контроллера модуля..

а там все значение выводятся нормально, нужно только сортировать по значению sort

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545544/how-to-sort-a-multidemensional-array-by-an-inner-key

Comment: не работает, вставил перед foreach

Answer (score 0):

> Как можно сортировать массив по параметру sort

Если имелось ввиду по значению `sort`, то так

```
...
usort($setting['butopbanner_module'], function($a, $b){
  return ($a['sort'] - $b['sort']);
});

foreach ($setting['butopbanner_module'] as $key => $value) {
  // ...
}
...
```